# Why am I getting an invalid select exception, when the same simple selector works in the chrome console?

Tags: selenium, geb

I am using GEB with selenium.

This is one of the selectors I was getting `invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified` for

`$("button:contains('Accept')")`

If I run this selector through the chrome console it is able to find the element, but when I run the same selector through GEB/selenium is states it is an invalid selector

In the stack trace it also has this:

`*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=button:contains('Accept')}` Again I do not see anything wrong with this selector.

if I change the code to use an xpath expression instead it works.

seleniumVersion = '3.13.0'

Answer (score 3):

Apparently for GEB the syntax for defining the above selector would look like this:

`$("button", text: contains('Accept'))`

If you do it this way then it works

Comment: It's because ":contains" is not a valid CSS3 selector but a jQuery only extension and WebDriver which is the underlying library in Geb only supports CSS3 selectors (and rightly so in my opinion) and not jQuery selector extensions.